# Protected parameters in method declaration?

Tags: python

I'm reviewing a colleague's code and he's done something I've never even thought to do before:

```
@staticmethod
def a_class_method(_parameter='Default') -> tuple:
```

Is it kosher to declare a method/function parameter as private in Python? To me, underscore means 'don't touch this (unless you are aware of the consequences)' while making something a parameter means the opposite - Feel free to enter a variable here.

Comment: I'd rather ask your colleague, but this is sometimes used to mark the currently unused arguments so that e.g. `pylint` doesn't complain about them.

Comment: Also, in case if `'Default'` is some global variable in the real code, that can be an optimisation trick, since accessing globals is slower than locals in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen it either, and I don't think it makes sense. You can mark the method itself with underscore. But parameters, are *meant* to be known to the caller of the function. In my view, giving a hint in the signature that the parameter is going to be assigned to a member variable of the same name, rather breaks than enforces encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a big issue, but you'd rather ask you colleague what do they mean under that code. But in any case for any stranger, that code doesn't look obvious so it should be rewritten IMHO.